# Tips for functional equations using continuity

Tags: continuity, contest-math, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Can someone give me some tips and techniques for problems that ask to find continuous functions that verify a functional equation. This is a new type of problems for me. The only thing I know is to give x and y some trivial values and try finding a new function so I can rewrite the functional equation. Then I hope for Cauchy functional equations type or for some iterative way to solve the equation using limits and the continuity. How you guys usually do this type of problems? What techniques are you using?

Comment: I think you might need to be more specific here. Though one thing you can do is solve the functional equation on a dense set, then use continuity to extrapolate all of the other values.

For example, suppose you can first determine the value of the function $f$ on all of the integers. Then, you can extend to the rationals. Then, to extend the irrationals, you can just take a sequence of rationals that converge to that irrational and figure out $f(\text{irrational})$ using continuity.

Comment: Can you give me an example of problem where I can use this idea?

Comment: Sure, if you want to solve Cauchy's Functional Equation $$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$

Comment: Also, I saw that the tag on this post was contest math. If you're curious about contest math, it might be more helpful for you to go to artofproblemsolving.com and post on the forums there; that site is dedicated to contest math

Comment: Thanks for the forum! I am talking about problems like this: We have $f:R\rightarrow$$R$ continuous function with the propriety $f(xy)+f(x+y)=f(xy+y)+f(x)$ for any $x,y$ real numbers. There is a set of techniques or tips for this type of problems?

Comment: Hm so I'm not sure immediately how to go about this, but I'd first play around with it and try to determine $f$ for all integers. Then, you can try to extend $f$ to the rationals, and that should be enough.